# Auto Implemented properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

objectdatasource is not referencing the correct constructor depending on the parameters

I have(scaled down version)

```
    private int m_Code;
    private string m_FamCode;
    private string m_LastName;
    private string m_FirstName;
    private string m_Init;
    private DateTime chargeDate;
    private string tranCode;
    private decimal paidAmt;
    private string description;
```

Then I have the get\set for each

```
public int M_Code
        {
            get { return m_Code; }
            set { m_Code = value; }
        }
```

Then I have 3 different constructors that look like the following but pass different amount of properties to each one.

```
public BBNMemberDetails(DateTime cDate, string tCode, decimal pAmt, string desc)
        {
            this.chargeDate = cDate;
            this.tranCode = tCode;
            this.paidAmt = pAmt;
            this.description = desc;
        }


 public BBNMemberDetails(int m_Code, string m_FamCode, string m_LastName, string m_FirstName, string m_Init)
    {
        this.m_Code = m_Code;
        this.m_FamCode = m_FamCode;
        this.m_LastName = m_LastName;
        this.m_FirstName = m_FirstName;
        this.m_Init = m_Init;
        this.m_Title = m_Title;
```

}

default constructor

```
  public BBNMemberDetails() { }
```

For some reason the only constructor that is being referenced is the one with all my properties. The constructor where I would like to just grab the transaction information is not being referenced. I am using a List in combination of a sqldatareader that references a storedprocedure to grab the values also then just an objectdatasource on the front end to attach it to the gridview. But my gridview shows all the properties instead of just the few I want it to show in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a constructor, you get a complete object.

The object isn't pared down because you call a constructor that initializes fewer members.

Comment: To follow up on the answer, you can trim the properties shown by explicitly setting the columns in your markup and setting `AutoGenerateColumns = "false" on the gridview.

Comment: so for each set of properties i should create a new class is that the proper way to approach this?

Comment: Looking at your variables it seems you need a Member class and a Transaction class.  You are not going to learn OOP design in a thread, you need to study a bit.  BTW - You shouldn't post multiple-identical questions.

Comment: Believe me I am studying this does not come as easy to me to learn from a book. These projects and questions I have been working on is from me trying new things so I can get my feet wet. They are meaningless projects. However when reading a book or watching the million videos I watch I tend to understand it because everyone shows the most basic examples possible which does not help me learn to build robust business applications one bit.